# Do things in random order?

Tags: python, random

Is there any way in Python to do things in random order? Say I'd like to run `function1()`, `function2()`, and `function3()`, but not necessarilly in that order, could that be done? The obvious answer is to make a list and choose them randomly, but how would you get the function name from the list and actually run it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple. Python functions are just objects, that happen to be callable. So you can store them in a list, and then call them using the call operator (`()`).

Make your list of functions, shuffle them with [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.shuffle), and then loop through, calling them.

```
to_call = [function1, function2, function3]
random.shuffle(to_call)
for f in to_call:
    f()
```

If you wanted to store the returned values, you could add them to a list, and that would make a good case for a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
returned_values = [f() for f in to_call]
```